# Search a whole word in a column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, where-clause

I need to write T-SQL query that returns records in which `Text` column value contains the whole word `he`.

How can I do so?

```
SELECT
  CreationDate,
  Text
FROM Comments
WHERE Text LIKE '%he'
ORDER BY Id DESC
```

This query returns records with `Text` column values containing `he` as a part of words, e.g. `the distribution`.

Comment: Have you had a look at Fulltext Indexes? *If* I recall correctly, however, "he" is a default stop word, so you'll likely need to create your own stop word list. Using a `LIKE` you can get the result you're after, but it won't be particularly performant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
where ' ' + text + ' ' like '% he %'
```

Comment: You need also to remove all non alphebetic chars with the TRANSLATE function by a space before using the LIKE. As an instance the sentence "Did he?" will not be find with the actual GMB solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here I send my query according to what I understood about your requirement.

```
  SELECT O.create_date, 
         O.modify_date, 
         T.COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM Information_Schema.COLUMNS T 
            INNER JOIN sys.objects O
                    ON O.name = T.TABLE_NAME
                   AND O.type = 'U'
   WHERE T.TABLE_NAME   = 'table_name' 
     AND T.COLUMN_NAME  LIKE '%he%'
```

Regards.